# Save variable to use over classes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass strings to all pages in my android app. When the user logs in I save userName and others to strings. I want to send the strings over multiple pages. How can I do that?

I have tried to send it through Intent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Help.class);  
myIntent.putExtra("userName", userNameString);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

But when I go to another page I dont want to keep sending the data through Intent every time.

I have tried to get it from the class where I parse and put them in strings

```
HomeScreen home = new HomeScreen();
String userName= home.userNameString;
```

But since i am creating a new instance of the HomeScreen then `userNameString` is `null`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does HomeScreen extend Activity?

Comment: You could always extend the application class and access its variables through getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of using a static or instance variable to hold this state as the memory state of an Android application can be in flux.  Data only stored in memory can be destroyed without your knowledge if your application process is killed while in the background.

The simplest mechanism would be to persist your data into `SharedPreferences` that you can access from any place in the application.  So, first you save the string that you get from login (this is called inside an Activity, FYI):

```
//Write the username string to preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putString("userName", userNameString).commit();
```

Then elsewhere in your application (i.e. other Activity instances) can read that string:

```
//Read the username string
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userName = prefs.getString("userName", "");
```

With `SharedPreferences`, your values are actually persisted, meaning they will live forever on disk and won't go away just because your application's memory is reset (this is usually an advantage, especially for login information).  Because of this, you will also need to **remove** the string when your user "logs out" like so:

```
//Remove the username string from preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().remove("userName").commit();
```

There are also methods like `contains()` to allow you to check if the value is currently saved (is the user logged in?), etc.

Comment: You should also comment on encrypting this data, as its never a good idea to store this kind of information to file in plain text.

Comment: If the user is logging in, then the child `Activity` needs a way of knowing which user name was entered in its parent... maybe `SharedPreferences` would be the correct means of storing the data, but the child should probably be sent the username initially by means of an intent. Further, the username will always be available to the child with `getIntent` (even if the `Activity` is destroyed by the OS)

Answer (score 1):

The calling `Activity` is not guaranteed to remain in memory... the Android system may destroy it at any time.

If the child `Activity` depends on the user name, then the correct means of passing the information is with an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static variable and use it from everywhere:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static String userNameString;
}
```

Use it like:

```
Strign s = SomeClass.userNameString;
```

Change its value as:

```
SomeClass.userNameString = "new string";
```